# Verify that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ for the function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

$  f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{(2x-y)}{x+y},  & \text{if } (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\
0, & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$

My Attempt:
So according to me, we need to divide this question into two parts and solve these two parts individually. The first part is I did where we need to take the case $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and prove $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ I am facing the problem
in the second case where we need to take $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

When $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$:
$$
f_x=\frac{(3y)}{(x+y)^2}
$$

$$
f_y=\frac{(-3x)}{(x+y)^2}
$$

When $(x,y)=(0,0)$
$$
f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_y(h,0)-f_y(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-3}{h^2}=\infty
$$
$$
f_{yx}(0,0)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f_x(0,k)-f_x(0,0)}{k}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{3}{k^2}=\infty
$$

So how we will prove that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$.
please help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Type `f_x` to get $f_x$, and `\infty` to get $\infty$.

Comment: And avoid SCREAMING

Answer (score 1):

First an observation. The function is not defined when $x+y=0$ (with the exception of the point $(0,0)$), so I'll consider the domain of $f$ only on the points where it's defined.

We have $$f_x(x,y) = \frac{3y}{(x+y)^2}$$ for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ in the domain,
but for $f_x(0,0)$ we have
$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{2h-0}{h+0}- 0}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2}{h}$$ which doesn't exists.

Since $f_x(0,0)$ doesn't exists it makes no sense to talk about $f_{xy}$ at that point.